# How is Big O of selection sort calculated mathematically?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Can someone please explain in plain English how to calculate it?
I know that you have to visit `n+2+(n-1)+2+...+2+2` elements, but how do you get to `1/2n^2 + 5/2n - 3?`  Thanks!

Comment: it as in how to get to O(n^2)

Comment: summation of integers over n is quadratic and so it leads to O(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n + 2 + (n - 1) + 2 + ... + 2 + 2` is equal to `(n + 2) + (n + 1) + ... + 4`. It's an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) and its sum is calculated as `(n + 2 + 4) * (n + 2 - 4 + 1) / 2`. It's equal to `(n + 6) * (n - 1) / 2` and finally `1/2 * n^2 + 5/2 * n - 3`.

`f(n) = O(g(n))` means there exists such constant `C` that `f(n) <= C * g(n)` for all sufficiently large n. If n is considered as natural number then `1/2 * n^2 + 5/2 * n - 3 = O(n^2)` with `C = 3/2` for example.

Comment: Not "for all n" but rather for all *sufficiently large* n. The notion is asymptotic.